# Keras: How to concatenate input layer with output layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to replicate the network from:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.07176.pdf

I see their implementation in
https://github.com/wentaozhu/protein-cascade-cnn-lstm/blob/master/cb6133.py

I am trying to train on the Q8 task only, with no solvent task. I am trying to concatenate the [512, 50] embedding layer to the [512, 22] output layer, but I keep getting various errors. This is how I am trying to concatenate at the moment:

```
main_input = Input(shape=(maxlen_seq,), dtype='int32', name='main_input')
# Defining an embedding layer mapping from the words (n_words) to a vector of len 50
# input_orig = K.reshape(input, (maxlen_seq, n_words))
x = Embedding(input_dim=n_words, output_dim=50, input_length=maxlen_seq)(main_input)

aux_input = Input(shape=(maxlen_seq, n_words), name='aux_input')
x = concatenate([x, aux_input], axis=-1)
# ... rest of model ...
```

The model compiles fine with model.compile():

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
main_input (InputLayer)         (None, 512)          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_27 (Embedding)        (None, 512, 50)      1100        main_input[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
aux_input (InputLayer)          (None, 512, 22)      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_54 (Concatenate)    (None, 512, 72)      0           embedding_27[0][0]               
                                                                 aux_input[0][0]                  
________________________________________________________________________________________
...
```

But I get a `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected aux_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (4464, 512)`

The model is defined as:

```
model = Model([main_input, aux_input], [y1, y2])
```

And fit as:

```
model.fit({'main_input':X_train,
           'aux_input': X_train},
          {'main_output': y_train,
           'aux_output': y_train},
          batch_size=128, epochs=20, callbacks=[early, best_model],
          validation_data=({'main_input':X_val,
                            'aux_input': X_val},
                           {'main_output': y_val,
                            'aux_output': y_val}),
                            verbose=1)
```

Comment: From the model summary, we see two inputs are different shape.  So you cannot pass a same data to both.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I am trying to concatenate embedding_27 and aux_input, and concatenate_54 gives shape (None, 512, 72) as expected. Is there's some sort of reshaping that I could do?

Comment: I mean your `fit` call.  `model.fit({'main_input':X_train, 'aux_input': X_train} ...`  You are passing the same `X_train`.  But main and aux should have different shape.

Comment: What would the different shapes be? main_input is the embedding of size 50, whereas aux_input should be the one-hot vectors of size 22. I don't think I would modify X_train before passing them in?

Comment: Then you need to make one-hot vectors of size 22 outside and pass it to the aux input.

Comment: Thanks for that! Doing the one hot vector conversion before passing into aux_input works. The next issue I'm running is now in model.fit, which is shape being called on a NoneType object (y.shape[0]). Is this because I have only 1 output but 2 inputs? Do I then have to have a 1-1 ratio of inputs and outputs?

Comment: Can you add a small reproducible example to the question and clarify what you want to achieve?